# Refresh page content after dismiss popover . IONIC 3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an application tabs whit 4 Tabs, and each tab shows some data according to a configuration. The page have a header that contains a popover component with the settings option on it. 
After the user set some configuration on settings and back to some tab page, that page must refresh the content.

I am using the ionViewDidEnter or ionViewWillEnter lifecycle events and check if the previous settings have been changed but the event hasn't been being catch, only when I change to other tab page.

Tab page A

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  ionViewDidEnter(){
    if(this.client.doClientChanged(this.clientName)){
      console.log("changed");
    }
    else{
      console.log("not changed");
    }
  }
  ionViewWillEnter(){
    console.log("test")
  }
}
```

Header component

```
export class PrimeHeaderComponent {
  constructor(public popoverCtrl: PopoverController) {}

  presentPopover(event: any) {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(MenuPage);
    popover.present({
      ev: event
    });
  }
}
```

Popover Component

```
export class MenuPage {

  constructor(
    public viewCtrl: ViewController, private navCtrl: NavController) {}

  openConfig(){    
    this.navCtrl.push(ConfigPage);    
  }
}
```

When I chose the configuration, I back to the previous page that still shows the popover, and when I dismiss the popover, nothing happen with the lifecycle events.

Comment: can you share a bit more what do you mean by configuration? is that pure data or is there any like css style changes etc?

Comment: Yes. It is pure data. I have a lot of users and the administrator can see anything about the user on the app, but I need to select one, two or more customer and then refresh the data. I've already solved the problem, I will post in a few hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `.onDidDismiss()` of the [popover controller](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/)

```
let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(MenuPage);

popover.onDidDismiss(() => {
  //your action here
});

popover.present({
  ev: event
});
```